# Find Compound Words in List of Words - Python

Tags: python

I have a simple list of words I need to filter, but each word in the list has an accompanying "score" appended to it which is causing me some trouble. The input list has this structure:

```
lst = ['FAST;5','BREAK;60','FASTBREAK;40',
       'OUTBREAK;110','BREAKFASTBUFFET;35',
       'BUFFET;75','FASTBREAKPOINTS;60'
      ]
```

I am trying to figure out how to identify words in my list that are compounded solely from other words on the same list. For example, the code applied to `lst` above would produce:

```
ans = ['FASTBREAK:40','BREAKFASTBUFFET;35']
```

I found a [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40445859/14518985) that deals with a nearly identical situation , but in that instance, there are no trailing scores with the words on the list and I am having trouble dealing with these trailing scores on my list. The `ans` list must keep the scores with the compound words found. The order of the words in `lst` is random and irrelevant. Ideally, I would like the ans list to be sorted by the length of the word (before the `' ; '`), as shown above. This would save me some additional post-processing on ans.

I have figured out a way that works using ReGex and nested for loops (I will spare you the ugliness of my 1980s-esque brute force code, it's really not pretty), but my word list has close to a million entries, and my solution takes so long as to be completely unusable. I am looking for a solution a little more Pythonic that I can actually use. I'm having trouble working through it.

Comment: Why `'OUTBREAK;110'` and `'FASTBREAKPOINTS;60'` are ommited in the result list?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question would also be a whole lot clearer with sample inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes, they are omitted because OUT and POINTS are not on the list in this example.

Comment: You will still have non-compound results: for instance the word ‘generally’ isn’t a compound word ‘gene-rally’!! So, while you may get a list of contenders you will need to eliminate false positives somehow!

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do it like this: make a new list containing only the words. In a for loop go through this list, and within it look for the words that are part of the word of the outer loop. If they are found: replace the found part by an empty string. If afterwards the entire word is replaced by an empty string: show the word of the corresponding index of the original list.

EDIT: As was pointed out in the comments, there could be a problem with the code in some situations, like this one: `lst = ["BREAKFASTBUFFET;35", "BREAK;60", "BREAKFAST;18", "BUFFET;75"]`  In BREAKFASTBUFFET I first found that BREAK was a part of it, so I replaced that one with an empty string, which prevented BREAKFAST to be found. I hope that problem can be tackled by sorting the list descending by length of the word.

EDIT 2
My former edit was not flaw-proof, for instance is there was a word BREAKFASTEN, it shouldn't be "eaten" by BREAKFAST. This version does the following:

- make a list of candidates: all words that ar part of the word in investigation
- make another list of words that the word is started with
- keep track of the words in the candidates list that you've allready tried
- in a while True: keep trying until either the start list is empty, or you've successfully replaced all words by the candidates

```
lst = ['FAST;5','BREAK;60','FASTBREAK;40',
       'OUTBREAK;110','BREAKFASTBUFFET;35',
       'POINTS;25',
       'BUFFET;75','FASTBREAKPOINTS;60', 'BREAKPOINTS;15'
      ]
lst2 = [ s.split(';')[0] for s in lst ]

for i, word in enumerate(lst2):
    # candidates: words that are part of current word
    candidates = [ x for i2, x in enumerate(lst2) if x in word and i != i2 ]
    if len(candidates) > 0:
        tried = []
        word2 = word
        found = False
        while not found:
            # start: subset of candidates that the current word starts with
            start = [ x for x in candidates if word2.startswith(x) and x not in tried ]
            for trial in start:
                word2 = word2.replace(trial,'')
                tried.append(trial)
                if len(word2)==0:
                    print(lst[i])
                    found = True
                    break
            if len(candidates)>1:
                candidates = candidates[1:]
                word2=candidates[0]
            else:
                break
```

Comment: Hi @alkemyst, actually, I just found out that there is a flaw in my program, because it will now also find the well known word "BREFASTAK". So what we need to do is replace each found match with a space character instead of an empty string, and compare the length of the stripped string with zero. I will update my code.

Comment: Thank you @Marko. I hadn't even had a chance to look over any of the sample output to see the issue. I have updated my code.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, the provided code will not find a composition of the first word in `[BREAKFASTBUFFET, BREAK, BREAKFAST, BUFFET]`, right?

Comment: @BartVanLoon, In your case (if it were strings, with an added code), BREAKFASTBUFFET and BREAKFAST should show up, because those are the words that are made up entirely from other words in the list.

Comment: I just tried the code above with `lst = ["BREAKFASTBUFFET;35", "BREAK;60", "BREAKFAST;18", "BUFFET;75"]` and nothing shows up. This is because the algorithm goes through the list sequentially.

That's why in my answer I state that a more robust (but still brute force) solution would involve combinatorials.

Comment: @BartVanLoon I see, that would be a problem, hmm. Would it make a difference if I sorted the list descending by length? I will change my code accordingly. Or could there still be values missing?

Comment: @BartVanLoon I have made yet another edit to make it more robust. I think this does the job.

Comment: pre-sorting the list descending by length sounds like a good idea, but (without giving it much thought) I don't think it will prevent these scenarios entirely.

Comment: @BartVanLoon Have you seen my second update? I've abandoned the sort, because I saw it had some flaws.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that does the job. I'm sure it's not perfect for your situation (with a million entries), but perhaps can be useful in parts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           
                                                                                  
from collections import namedtuple                                                 
                                                                                 
Word = namedtuple("Word", ("characters", "number"))                                
separator = ";"    
                                                                             
lst = [                                                                            
    "FAST;5",                                                                      
    "BREAK;60",                                                                    
    "FASTBREAK;40",                                                                
    "OUTBREAK;110",                                                                
    "BREAKFASTBUFFET;35",                                                          
    "BUFFET;75",                                                                   
    "FASTBREAKPOINTS;60",                                                          
]                                                                                  
                                                                                 
words = [Word(*w.rsplit(separator, 1)) for w in lst]                                     
                                                                                 
                                                                                 
def findparts(oword, parts):                                                       
    if len(oword.characters) == 0:                                                 
        return parts                                                               
    for iword in words:                                                            
        if not parts and iword.characters == oword.characters:                     
            continue                                                               
        if iword.characters in oword.characters:
            parts.append(iword)                                                    
            characters = oword.characters.replace(iword.characters, "")                                                
            return findparts(Word(characters, oword.number), parts)                
    return []                                                                      
                                                                                 
                                                                                 
ans = []                                                                           
for word in words:                                                                 
    parts = findparts(word, [])                                                    
    if parts:                                                                      
        ans.append(separator.join(word))    
                                                                                 
print(ans)
```

It uses a recursive function that takes a word in your list and tries to assemble it with other words from that same list. This function will also present you with the actual atomic words forming the compound one.

It's not very smart, however. Here is an example of a composition it will not detect:
[BREAKFASTBUFFET, BREAK, BREAKFAST, BUFFET].

It uses a small detour using a namedtuple to temporarily separate the actual word from the number attached to it, assuming that the separator will always be `;`.

I don't think regular expressions hold an advantage over a simple string search here.

If you know some more conditions about the composition of the compound words, like for instance the maximum number of components, the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) combinatoric generators might help you to speed things up significantly and avoid missing the example given above too.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of speeding up the process but I doubt there is a polynomial solution.

So let's use multiprocessing, and do what we can to generate a meaningful result. The sample below is not identical to what you are asking for, but it does compose a list of apparently compound words from a large dictionary.

For the code below, I am sourcing https://gist.github.com/h3xx/1976236 which lists about 80,000 unique words in order of frequency in English.

The code below can easily be sped up if the input wordlist is sorted alphabetically beforehand, as each head of a compound will be immediately followed by it's potential compound members:

```
black
blackberries
blackberry
blackbird
blackbirds
blackboard
blackguard
blackguards
blackmail
blackness
blacksmith
blacksmiths
```

As mentioned in the comment, you may also need to use a semantic filter to identify true compound words - for instance, the word ‘generally’ isn’t a compound word for a ‘gene rally’ !! So, while you may get a list of contenders you will need to eliminate false positives somehow.

```py
# python 3.9
import multiprocessing as mp

# returns an ordered list of lowercase words to be used.
def load(name) -> list:
    return [line[:-1].lower() for line in open(name) if not line.startswith('#') and len(line) > 3]

# function that identifies the compounds of a word from a list.
# ... can be optimised if using a sorted list.
def compounds_of(word: str, values: list):
    return [w for w in values if w.startswith(word) and w.removeprefix(word) in values]

# apply compound finding across an mp environment
# but this is the slowest part
def compose(values: list) -> dict:
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        result = {(word, i): pool.apply(compounds_of, (word, values)) for i, word in enumerate(values)}
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # https://gist.github.com/h3xx/1976236
    words = load('wiki-100k.txt')  # words are ordered by popularity, and are 3 or more letters, in lowercase.
    words = list(dict.fromkeys(words))

    # remove those word heads which have less than 3 tails
    compounds = {k: v for k, v in compose(words).items() if len(v) > 3}

    # get the top 500 keys
    rank = list(sorted(compounds.keys(), key=lambda x: x[1]))[:500]

    # compose them into a dict and print
    tops = {k[0]: compounds[k] for k in rank}
    print(tops)
```